# How to pass a parameter from a Java controller to a Thymeleaf template

Tags: java, spring-boot, thymeleaf

I'm just trying to pass a parameter from a controller to a Thymeleaf template.
From the Thymeleaf documentation I understand that I can do it as below:

```
return "editor/{id}(id=" + newEditor.getIdEditor() + ")";
```

There is a function into the controller which receives the request

```
@GetMapping(value = "/editor/{id}")
```

but all I get is an error

> Error resolving template [editor/{id}(id=8)],

Maybe my approach is wrong and there is a proper way to do it, but I haven't found it.

Comment: What are you trying to do? Passing values into a Thymeleaf template (for use within the template), should be done through the `Model` object. Is that what you want? Otherwise, what effect are you trying to achieve here?

Answer (score 2):

The return-value from controller method should be a Thymeleaf template name, and that is what the error message tries to tell you.

If you are trying to return a value for use in your Thymeleaf template:

```
@GetMapping("/yourendpointname")
public String yourControllerMethod(final Model model) {

    ...

    model.addAttribute("idEditor", newEditor.getIdEditor());
    return "template_name";
}
```

You can now assemble the URL from your question inside the Thymeleaf template.